# Back to The Future style Time Updates in Doctor Who

Tags: doctor-who, time-travel, back-to-the-future

Is "The Angels Take Manhattan" the first time in Doctor Who we see time changing in the present because of an action in the past?

> When Amy is touched by the Angel and sent back in time to Rory, the gravestone changes in front of The Doctor's (and ours) eyes, much like various items in Back to the Future do (e.g. Newspapers, Photographs) as actions in the past alter the future.

The best comparison I can think of is at the end of Back to the Future part 3 when Marty doesn't partake in the dragrace, the fax that Jennifer had kept from 2015 where Marty had been fired has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen that episode yet, but I'd say "no?". Note the question mark.

In the second episode with the Pandorica they play this "did it before, have to do it, will do it" stuff in a quite intense and obvious way (especially the Sonic Screwdriver). The changes aren't visible in plain sight though and more of the "it's just like that" way.

Although there have been other incidents being close to something like that (not necessarily directly visible or experienced):

- The first episode with the Weeping Angels.
- The first season episode with Rose's dad.
- The episode in season 6 (or 5?) with the hospice planet.
- The christmas episode of season 6 (with the old Scrooge-like guy).

Comment: I think the last one is the closest, but IIRC in each round trip in that episode the changes occurred at once.  It didn't happen "in front of our eyes".

Comment: Yes, they're not directly visible for the viewer, except in the christmas episode (if you count the recorded movie).